# QApplication on Android, started from JNI leads up to SEGFAULT

Tags: android-studio, qt, java-native-interface, aar

The main goal is to develop an .apk in Android Studio with qt based shared libraries (.so) onboard and start hidden qt event loop (QCoreApplication) in there.

---

###### The first of all,

I were concerned on how to make an Android archive (.aar) in QtCreator to use that in any target `.apk` as is - but it's wrong way because QtCreator doesn't support Android archives from the box. By the way to make a `.aar` instead of `.apk` we should change build.gradle inside `cmake` build directory like on the picture

[image]

But now its no matter from where we'll get `.so` to bring them into Android Studio project.

###### Android Studio project

Then we should create an activity based `AndroidStudio` project and then a `SdkService` class with native method `initSdk` that should be called to start our hidden native processing. Here is the path of mentioned class: `AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/java/io/company/companySdk/SdkService.java`

AndroidStudio project overview

[image]

###### JNI header

Then to generate JNI header I used `javac`:

```sh
$ pwd
/home/rozhkov/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/java/io/company/companySdk
$ javac -h . SdkService.java
```

Here is `initSdk` definition to include it in qtcreator project from `io_company_companySdk_SdkService.h`:

```cpp
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_io_company_companySdk_SdkService_initSdk
  (JNIEnv *, jclass);
```

###### QtCreator project

I created **Qt Widgets Application** because qtcreator generates `androiddeployqt` step for that kind of project. CMAKE type of project is most common for me.

It's important to not take off linking with Widgets qt library

Here are simple `CMakeLists.txt` and `main.cpp` following:

###### CMakeLists.txt

```
make_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

project(sample_service VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

set(CMAKE_AUTOUIC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(QT NAMES Qt6 Qt5 COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Core Widgets REQUIRED)

set(PROJECT_SOURCES
        main.cpp
)

if(${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} GREATER_EQUAL 6)
    qt_add_executable(sample_service
        MANUAL_FINALIZATION
        ${PROJECT_SOURCES}
    )
endif()

target_link_libraries(sample_service PRIVATE Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR}::Widgets)

if(QT_VERSION_MAJOR EQUAL 6)
    qt_finalize_executable(sample_service)
endif()
```

###### main.cpp

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <jni.h>

#include <android/log.h>

#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QJniEnvironment>

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_io_company_companySdk_SdkService_initSdk(JNIEnv *, jclass);

class ServiceHolder
{
public:
    typedef std::unique_ptr<std::thread> UniqueThreadPtr;
    static void init_app_worker() {
        if (_appThread)
            return;
        _appThread = std::make_unique<std::thread>([]() {
            int argc = 0;
            using namespace std::chrono_literals;
            QCoreApplication app(argc, nullptr);
            app.exec();
        });
    }
private:
    static UniqueThreadPtr _appThread;
};

ServiceHolder::UniqueThreadPtr ServiceHolder::_appThread;

extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_io_company_companySdk_SdkService_initSdk(JNIEnv * env, jclass)
{
    int argc = 0;
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "SdkConnect", "Java_io_company_companySdk_SdkService_initSdk");
    if (QJniEnvironment::checkAndClearExceptions(env, QJniEnvironment::OutputMode::Verbose))
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "SdkConnect", "Java environment checked");
    }
    else
    {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "SdkConnect", "Java environment not checked");
    }
    ServiceHolder::init_app_worker();
}

jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM * aVm, void * aReserved)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "SdkConnect", "Company sdk on load");
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

###### Deploy to Android Studio

Qtcreator's build result is a `android-build-debug.apk` in cmake build directory. Right from there we should copy all related `.so` into `jniLibs` special directory from where that shared libs should be loaded as part of target `.apk`.

The following instructions discover how it can be done:

```sh
$ pwd
/home/rozhkov/sources/android/sample_service/build-sample_service-Android_Qt_6_1_2_Clang_x86_64-Release/android-build/build/outputs/apk/debug
$ mkdir extracted
$ unzip -qod extracted/ android-build-debug.apk 
$ cp extracted/lib/x86_64/* ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/
$ mv ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libsample_service_x86_64.so ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/libsample_service.so 
$ ls ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/
libc++_shared.so                        libplugins_imageformats_qjpeg_x86_64.so                                           libplugins_styles_qandroidstyle_x86_64.so  libQt6Network_x86_64.so
libplugins_imageformats_qgif_x86_64.so  libplugins_networkinformationbackends_androidnetworkinformationbackend_x86_64.so  libQt6Core_x86_64.so                       libQt6Widgets_x86_64.so
libplugins_imageformats_qico_x86_64.so  libplugins_platforms_qtforandroid_x86_64.so                                       libQt6Gui_x86_64.so                        libsample_service.so
```

###### Call natives from Java

The next step is loading shared library from Java and call mentioned `initSdk`. I extened `MainActivity` class in the following way:

Call natives from java

[image]

###### Running Android application - SEGFAULT

At last our Android application sample running on x86_64 emulator device.
Always when sample `.apk` was running there happened SEGFAULT in `libsample_service.so` on `QCoreApplication` constructor.

In stack-trace we can see it happens exactly in `QJniEnvironmentPrivate`:

stack-trace

[image]

There is no matter if it used Qt 6.1.2 or, for example, 5.1.15 - that segfault happened always.

###### Questions

There are remaining options to do that I not made in time.

For example may be that happens because of app version not set.

> `#04 pc 000000000032da4a  /data/app/rozhkov.example.myapplication-2/lib/x86_64/libQt6Core_x86_64.so (_ZNK23QCoreApplicationPrivate10appVersionEv+372)`

Or may be it is [QtAndroidService](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-services.html) is better for that kind of tasks.

Or may be anything else...

Does anyone know how it should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following steps guide you in proper way how to manage Android Studio project to make possible start QtService with some service activities on native side of android application.

###### Qt and QtCreator:

1. There are QtAndroidExtras in Qt 5.15, so you should build project under this version.
2. In your build configuration you should enable a few build options for any architecture that you need.
   [image]
3. To start QtService you can use simple code:

```cpp
#include <android/log.h>
#include <QtAndroidExtras/QAndroidService>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    QAndroidService app(argc, argv);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "Sample service", "Service being started");
    return app.exec();
}
```

###### Then in Android Studio project you need to:

1. Create `jniLibs` folder and copy all `.so` architecture related sets, that qt placed in `android-build/libs` this way:

```sh
[@ libs]$ pwd 
/home/rozhkov/sources/android/service_apk/build-service_apk-Android_Qt_5_15_0_Clang_Multi_Abi_369ced-Release/android-build/libs
[@ libs]$ ls
arm64-v8a  armeabi-v7a  QtAndroidBearer.jar  QtAndroidExtras.jar  QtAndroid.jar  x86  x86_64 
[@ libs]$ cp -R x86* arm* ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/jniLibs/    
[@ libs]$
```

2. Copy all `.jar` files:

```sh
[@ libs]$ cp QtAndroid*.jar ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/java/jar/
```

3. You'll need related `.aidl`s from Qt. Copy them too:

```sh
[@ src]$ pwd 
/home/rozhkov/Qt/5.15.0/Src/qtbase/src/android/java/src
[@ src]$ cp -R org ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/aidl/
```

4. And resource `libs.xml` from qt build directory:

```sh
[@ values]$ pwd 
/home/rozhkov/sources/android/service_apk/build-service_apk-Android_Qt_5_15_0_Clang_Multi_Abi_369ced-Release/android-build/res/values
[@ values]$ cp libs.xml ~/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication7/app/src/main/res/values/
```

5. Pupulate `AndroidManifest.xml` like in official Qt guide [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/android-services.html], but you need replace %% instractions manually. I got that values from AndroidManifest of `.apk`, built under Qt
   It's of mine:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="rozhkov.example.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication.NoActionBar" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="io.company.companySdk.QtAndroidService"  android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" android:process=":qt">

            <meta-data android:name="android.app.lib_name" android:value="service_apk"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_sources_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_sources"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.repository" android:value="default"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.qt_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/qt_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundled_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/bundled_libs"/>
            <!-- Deploy Qt libs as part of package -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.bundle_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>

            <!-- Run with local libs -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.use_local_qt_libs" android:value="1"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.libs_prefix" android:value="/data/local/tmp/qt/"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_libs_resource_id" android:resource="@array/load_local_libs"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.load_local_jars" android:value="jar/QtAndroid.jar:jar/QtAndroidExtras.jar"/>
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.static_init_classes" android:value=""/>
            <!-- Run with local libs -->

            <!-- Background running -->
            <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="true"/>
            <!-- Background running -->
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

6. At last you should define a java class, inherits QtService. I got it in Qt docs:

```java
package io.company.companySdk;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtService;

public class QtAndroidService extends QtService
{
    private static final String TAG = "QtAndroidService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating Service");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "Destroying Service");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int ret = super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return ret;
    }

}
```

and start it from default AndroidStudio `MainActivity`:

```java
...

import io.company.companySdk.QtAndroidService;

...


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
        startService(new Intent(this, QtAndroidService.class));
...
```

##### Now it should be all right ;)